# Key errors on this code, included errors at the bottom

Tags: google-colaboratory, keyerror

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("Student-Grades.csv")
df.head(5)
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['final grade'][i] = (df['final'][i] + df['mid'][i]) / 2
    if df['final grade'][i] >= 90 :
        df['letter grade'][i] = 'A'
    elif df['final grade'][i] >= 80  and df['final grade'][i] < 90  :
        df['letter grade'][i] = 'B'
    elif df['final grade'][i] >= 70  and df['final grade'][i] < 80  :
        df['letter grade'][i] = 'C'
    elif df['final grade'][i] >= 60  and df['final grade'][i] < 70  :
        df['letter grade'][i] = 'D'
    elif df['final grade'][i] < 60 :
        df['letter grade'][i] = 'F'

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['final grade'][i] >= 60 :
        df['pass/fail'][i] = "Pass"
    else:
        df['pass/fail'][i] = "Fail"

df.describe()  
df.median() 
df[['mid','final','final grade']].plot.bar() 
df.groupby(['letter grade']).sum().plot(kind='pie', y='final')
df.groupby(['pass/fail']).sum().plot(kind='pie', y='final') 
print(df.describe())  
print(df.median()) 
df.to_excel("/content/data_final.xlsx")  # to save data in excel
```

These are the errors that I am being shown for some reason.

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)

3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803             except KeyError as err:

4 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'final'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
3805             except TypeError:
3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'final'

After I run the code it prompts me to upload my file. Once I got I got the string of errors that I attached at the bottom.